# Communication between a C# application and C++ DLL

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, dll

I am currently building an audio streamer and I have a CPP .dll that I use functions of inside the WPF C# GUI.

The program needs to deal with sorts of events such as

- Lower/Increase Volume
- Manipulate Equalizer Bands

To this point I have used named events to deal with this issue. What would be a better way of handling all those events from the GUI to the .dll?  The events system I use (.dll spawns a thread which while-s on a WaitForMultipleObjects), or would it be better/smarter/more-beneficial or just better-practice to use a named pipe instead?

Comment: Interop? .. . .

Comment: If you are ok being beholden to Windows platform COM would probably be the way to go.

Comment: @whatsisname: You don't need COM.  You can call DLL's with C calling convention from C#.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: that is true, but you have the hassle of creating a C wrapper API around your objects. While COM isn't hassle free either, it can provide a better C# <-> C++ interface for objects.

Comment: If they live in different OS processes, named pipe is indeed a suitable choice.

Answer (score 6):

You can call from C# to C/C++ directly using a technology known as P/Invoke.  With P/Invoke, a C++ function can be made to look just like a C# function.

Here's a simple example from [this article in MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx):

#### C Method Definition

```
BOOL MessageBeep(
  UINT uType   // beep type
);
```

#### P/Invoke Definition in C# of method in C

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
static extern Boolean MessageBeep(UInt32 beepType);
```

#### Calling the C method from C#

```
MessageBeep(0);
```

Now, isn't that simple & clean?  Much of the .NET Base Class Library is implemented as C/C++ code with a P/Invoke wrapper and a C# facade.  The .NET team itself uses P/Invoke rather than COM for this type of interop, it's simpler and more efficient.

A great resource for finding how to write P/Invoke method definitions is [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/).

Comment: This only works well if the API only exhibits C types. Using an API that exhibits C++ types that way is problematic.